# How to save and restore the convolution autoencoder neural network model

Tags: python-3.x

I use the convolutional autoencoder neural network method to train my model and then save it, but when I restore my model to reconstruct the image which is similar to the training image, the reconstruction result is very bad and the loss is large. I am not sure if I am wrong with saving and reading files.

Training model and save it!

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim], name = "X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dim], name = "Y")
keepprob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = "K")
pred = cae(x, weights, biases, keepprob, imgsize)["out"]       
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(cae(x, weights, biases, keepprob,imgsize)["out"] - tf.reshape(y, shape=[-1, imgsize, imgsize, 1])))      
learning_rate = 0.01    
optm = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)   
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
sess = tf.Session()
save_model = os.path.join(PATH,'temp_saved_model')
saver      = tf.train.Saver()           
tf.add_to_collection("COST",  cost)
tf.add_to_collection("PRED",  pred)    

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())           
mean_img = np.zeros((dim))

batch_size = 100
n_epochs   = 1000   

for epoch_i in range(n_epochs):

    for batch_i in range(ntrain // batch_size):                              
        trainbatch = np.array(train)                    
        trainbatch = np.array([img - mean_img for img in trainbatch])           
        sess.run(optm, feed_dict={x: trainbatch, y: trainbatch, keepprob: 1.})       

save_path = saver.save(sess, save_model)
print('Model saved in file: %s' %save_path)    
sess.close()
```

Restoring the model and try to reconstruct the image.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
save_model = os.path.join(PATH + 'SaveModel/','temp_saved_model.meta')
imgsize  = 64
dim      = imgsize * imgsize
mean_img = np.zeros((dim))   

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver  = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_model)
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(PATH + 'SaveModel/'))         

    cost  = tf.get_collection("COST")[0]
    pred  = tf.get_collection("PRED")[0]       

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("X:0")
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Y:0")
    k = graph.get_tensor_by_name("K:0")        

    for i in range(10):           
        test_xs = np.array(data)             
        test    = load_image(test_xs, imgsize)
        test    = np.array([img - mean_img for img in test])       

    print ("[%02d/%02d] cost: %.4f" % (i, 10, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: test, y: test, K: 1.})))
```

The loss value in the training process is 1.321..., but the reconstruction loss is 16545.10441... Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you talking about saving and loading model weights and parametrs?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how to restore model and reconstruct the image.

Comment: Could you run the restore function and run `print(sess.run(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(Path + 'SaveModel/')))` before the `saver.restore()` function, basically your approach looks correct, l want to see if all paths are added correctly.

Comment: ValueError: Fetch argument 'D:/.../SaveModel/temp_saved_model' cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (The name D:/.../SaveModel/temp_saved_model' looks a like a Tensor name, but is not a valid one. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".)

Comment: Oh Sorry you don't need sess.run while printing it, can you try it again as `print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(Path + 'SaveModel/'))`

Comment: also add the extension `.ckpt` in your model name, sometimes in Windows files without extensions break.

Comment: The print is as follows:
D:/..../SaveModel/temp_saved_model.ckpt

Comment: import this `from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file`, then use `latest_ckp = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('Path + 'SaveModel/')`
`print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(latest_ckp, all_tensors=True, tensor_name='')` See which variables are being stored. (Do this in the restore time)

Comment: Use the same method to obtain tensors which are being saved, check if tensors saved and tensors restored are same.

Comment: I have checked that the tensors save and the tensors restored are different.

Comment: Save the model before running the prediction graph and then see if the tensors still vary.

Comment: If I save the model before running the prediction graph, the tensors saved and the tensors restored are the same. But the reconstruction image and loss are still worse.

Comment: The Images that you are using for model accuracy before and after, are they exactly the same Images or they just come from same dataset?

Comment: My training_image = image_data[0:int(0.8*len(image_data))] and my testing_image = image_data[int(0.8*len(image_data)):]
And the loss of the testing_image ~ 1.321...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
After restoring the model, I use the part of testing_image to reconstruct, but the result is different and bad.

Comment: Your Restore and Save functions are in Different files right? Because `tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_model)` Adds the imported graph to the existing graph.

Comment: Also keepprob changes from 'K' to 'k' while building graph after restore. Also why are you feeding the same data in feed_dict for x and y, X is supposed to be logits and Y is supposed to be labels.

Comment: Moreover in your saver part you are checking training loss `recon = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: testbatch, keepprob: 1.}) ` This only gives predictions, `cost  = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: test, y: test, k: 1.})` This statement is only present in restore model.

Comment: I have tried to compile my points into an answer below, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that Your Restore and Save functions are in Different files.

There are a few problems that I have debugged so far,

1. keepprob changes from 'K' to 'k' while building graph after restore.
2. You are facing same Images as Logits and labels (Doesn't make sense until you are trying to learn an Identity function)
3. You are calculating training cost before saving the model and validation/test cost after restoring the model.

Your code in saver

```
recon = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: testbatch, keepprob: 1.})          

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, n_examples, figsize=(15, 4))
        for example_i in range(5):
            axs[0][example_i].matshow(np.reshape(testbatch[example_i, :], (imgsize, imgsize)), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
            axs[1][example_i].matshow(np.reshape(np.reshape(recon[example_i, ...], (dim,)) + mean_img, (imgsize, imgsize)), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
        plt.show()
```

Your code in restore function

```
        recon = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: test, k: 1.})            
        cost  = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: test, y: test, k: 1.})

        if (i % 2) == 0:
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, n_examples, figsize=(15, 4))
            for example_i in range(n_examples):
                axs[0][example_i].matshow(np.reshape(test[example_i, :], (imgsize, imgsize)), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
                axs[1][example_i].matshow(np.reshape(np.reshape(recon[example_i, ...], (dim,)) + mean_img, (imgsize, imgsize)), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
            plt.show()
```

Also nowhere in your code are you printing/plotting cost even in your recover module you are plotting `recon` variable

If you are trying to test autoencoder-decoder pair, to generate the original Image, your model is a bit too small(Shallow), If that makes sense, try implementing it, if you are confused, check out this link. https://pgaleone.eu/neural-networks/deep-learning/2016/12/13/convolutional-autoencoders-in-tensorflow/

And in any case, feel free to add comments for further clarification.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and tidy up the program to make an error here. In fact, I used five layers for encoder and decoder, respectively. I modify my code in the original post.